I can't fix the transparency of the navigation bar in swiftui
what I want is for the navigation bar to have a gray background, but despite changing this code I always have a transparent background
import SwiftUI

struct Settings: View {
    @State private var notificationsEnabled = false
    @State private var travelModeEnabled = false

    init(){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes=[.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color(.alternativeDark)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()

                VStack {
                    Form {
                        Section(header: Text("Personal Information").font(.headline).foregroundColor(.gray)) {
                            navigationRow(title: "Name", value: "Lorem Ipsum", destination: Text("Edit Name"))
                            navigationRow(title: "Birth Date", value: "Lorem Ipsum", destination: Text("Edit Birth Date"))
                            navigationRow(title: "Email", value: "Lorem Ipsum", destination: Text("Edit Email Address"))
                            navigationRow(title: "Phone Number", value: "Lorem Ipsum", destination: Text("Edit Phone Number"))
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))

                        Section(header: Text("Location").font(.headline).foregroundColor(.black)) {
                            navigationRow(title: "Current Location", value: "Lorem Ipsum", destination: Text("Edit Location"))
                            Toggle(isOn: $travelModeEnabled) {
                                Text("Holiday Mode")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .tint(.green)
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))

                        Section(header: Text("Notifications").font(.headline).foregroundColor(.gray)) {
                            Toggle(isOn: $notificationsEnabled) {
                                Text("Notifications")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .tint(.green)
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))

                        Section(header: Text("Manage Account").font(.headline).foregroundColor(.gray)) {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("Log Out tapped")
                            }) {
                                settingActionRow(title: "Log Out", icon: "rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.right", iconColor: .white)
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                print("Deactivate/Delete Account tapped")
                            }) {
                                settingActionRow(title: "Deactivate/Delete Account", icon: "trash", iconColor: .red)
                            }
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    }
                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
        .tint(.white)
    }

    private func navigationRow<Destination: View>(title: String, value: String, destination: Destination) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                Text(value)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }

    private func settingActionRow(title: String, icon: String, iconColor: Color) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: icon)
                .foregroundColor(iconColor)
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Settings()
}


What I want is to get navigation bar with a navigation header and navigation back button with a non-transparent and aligned gray background.
what I encountered in canvas

Add them out of the navigation stack:
.toolbarBackground(Color(hex: “#1a1a1a1a”)) .toolbarBackground(.visible,for:.navigationBar) .toolbarColorScheme(.dark)
